# Unexpected behavior from Popen once web app is deployed with apache

Tags: python, django, apache, subprocess, mod-wsgi

I have some code that uses subprocess to look at the logs from a git directory.  My code seems to work fine when executed in a local django dev environment.  Once deployed however (with Apache / mode_wsgi) the output from stdout read() comes back empty.  My development and production machine are the same right now, and I also tried making sure every file was readable.

Does anybody have an idea why Popen is not returning any output once deployed here?  Thanks.

```
def getGitLogs(projectName, searchTerm=None, since):
    os.chdir(os.path.join(settings.SCM_GIT, projectName))
    cmd = "git log --since {0} -p".format(since)
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, close_fds=True)
    output = p.stdout.read()
    ### here output comes back as expected in dev environment, but empty in once deployed
    return filterCommits(parseCommits(output), searchTerm)
```

Comment: is anything showing up in your apache server logs?

Comment: Nothing conspicuous at all... I even tried explicitly logginthe output variable, and it just says it's empty, not None or anything

Comment: Maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8494335/running-subprocess-popen-under-apachemod-wsgi-is-always-returning-an-error-with What's the return code of git log command (called from subprocess) ? What apache/mod_wsgi/python versions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Chain your `chdir` as part of your command (ie, `cd /foo/bar/zoo`)
2. Pass the full path to `git`

So your command would end up `cd /foo/bar/zoo && /usr/bin/git log --since`