# subprocess in views.py does not work

Tags: python, django, subprocess, beanstalkd

I need a function that starts several beanstalk workers before starting to record some videos with different cameras. All of these work in beanstalk. As I need to start the workers before the video record, I want to do a subprocess, but this does not work. The most curious thing is that if I run the subprocess alone in a different python script outside of this function (in the shell), this works! This is my code (the one which is not working):

```
os.chdir(path_to_the_manage.py)
subprocess.call("python manage.py beanstalk_worker -w 4",shell=True)
phase = get_object_or_404(Phase, pk=int(phase_id))
cameras = Video.objects.filter(phase=phase)

###########################################################################
##   BEANSTALK
###########################################################################

num_workers = 4
time_to_run = 86400

[...]

for camera in cameras:
    arg = phase_id +' '+settings.PATH_ORIGIN_VIDEOS +' '+camera.name 
    beanstalk_client.call('video.startvlcserver', arg=arg, ttr=time_to_run)
```

I want to include the subprocess because it's annoying to me if I have to run the beanstalk workers on each video record I wanna do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: when you say it does not work, are you getting an error message back? I'm assuming subprocess.call is just returning false? You may want to give the entire absolute path to where the script can be found. Maybe the views.py file cannot find it without an absolute path? I believe that is what I do when using subprocess.checkoutput on my linode server.

Comment: I don't get anything, it continues aparently working, but after a while, when I have to stop the video, I kill the process with os.kill, and the server throws a 500 error cause the process does not exist (the beanstalk_client.call has not been processed due to no beanstalk worker has been assigned). I'm using an absolute path to the manage.py.

Comment: Perhaps this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8494335/running-subprocess-popen-under-apachemod-wsgi-is-always-returning-an-error-with. I ran into same problem with python 2.7.3. You can overcome it by updating software and&or changing mod_wsgi/apache settings. In the end i switched from apache/mod_wsgi to nginx/uwsgi and have never ecountered it again.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure that [`subproccess.call`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) is what you are looking for.  I believe the issue is subproccess call is syncronous.  It doesn't spawn a new process but calls the command within the context of the web request.  This ties up resources and if the request times out or the user cancels, weird things could happen?

I have never used beanstalkd, but with celery (another job queue) the celeryd worker process is always running, waiting for jobs. This makes it easy to manage using supervisord.  If you look at beanstalkd deployment, I wouldn't be suprised if they recommend doing the same thing. This should include starting your beanstalk workers outside of the context of a view. 
From the command line

`python manage.py beanstalk_worker -w 4`

Once your beanstalkd workers are set up and running, you can send jobs to the queue using an async beanstalk api call, from your view

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/Vyho8TFew2I